# retrieve values from dynamically created dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Im creating a table and have added a few controls to it dynamically but the ID im assigning to these controls doesn't seem to be the same when i inspect them with firebug they seem to get a prefix so trying to do `FindControls("controlname")`when posting the page im not having much joy. example of the controls id: ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Monday_Normal_Small but then adding that prefix to the control name not having much joy either.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateMenu();   
}

public void CreateMenu()
{
    Table table = new Table();
    table.Attributes.Add("class", "table table-bordered");
    Label lbl = new Label();
    TableRow tr = new TableRow();
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();

    TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();
    lbl.Text = "Day";
    thc.Controls.Add(lbl);
    tr.Cells.Add(thc);

    thc = new TableHeaderCell();
    lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "Meal";
    thc.Controls.Add(lbl);
    tr.Cells.Add(thc);

    thc = new TableHeaderCell();
    lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "Normal";
    thc.Controls.Add(lbl);
    tr.Cells.Add(thc);

    thc = new TableHeaderCell();
    lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = "No Carb";
    thc.Controls.Add(lbl);
    tr.Cells.Add(thc);

    table.Rows.Add(tr);


    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) 
    {
        tr = new TableRow();
        tc = new TableCell();
        lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = "<h1 style='text-align:right;'>" + GetDay(i) + "</h1>";
        tc.Controls.Add(lbl);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);

        tc = new TableCell();
        lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Text = GetMeal(i);
        tc.Controls.Add(lbl);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);

        for (int j = 0; j <= 1; j++)
        {
            tc = new TableCell();
            Table dropdowntable = new Table();
            TableRow tr2 = new TableRow();
            TableCell tc2 = new TableCell();
            for (int k = 0; k <= 2; k++)
            {
                DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList(); 
                ddl.ID = GetDay(i) + "_" + GetType(j) + "_" + GetSize(k); 
                ddl.DataSource = numbers; 
                ddl.DataBind(); 
                tc2.Controls.Add(ddl);
            }
            tr2.Cells.Add(tc2);
            dropdowntable.Rows.Add(tr2);
            tc.Controls.Add(dropdowntable);
            tr.Cells.Add(tc);
        }
        table.Rows.Add(tr);
    }
    tableplaceholder.Controls.Add(table);
}
```

Ive changed the ClientIDMode of the ddl controls and no prefix but this doesnt seem to solve my problem, so i have a submit button at the bottom of my page and calling its click method trying this

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)FindControl(controlName);
    try
    {
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(ddl.SelectedValue);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
```

But no luck any ideas?

Comment: Use `ClientIDMode="Static"`  this will avoid `prefix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the issue i was having was when trying to FindControl() i was passing the control's ID and not the controls name, this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

To have same Id while inspecting in Firebug you should use one of the from the below.

1. Set Clientmode of dropdown to Static (so that it will have same ID in client side.

   ddl.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;

2.Use ClientId property in javascript to get the exact ID of the control.

```
var ddlValue = document.getElementById("<% ddl.ClientID %>");
```

Comment: Im using .NET 2.0 and dont seem to see ddl.ClientIDMode , only ddl.ClientID

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `ClientIDMode = Static`, for the control your are adding as explained in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx)

Hope this helps!